# Как добавить подсчет факториала в калькулятор (NASM)

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

у меня есть рабочий код с калькулятором никак не могу добавить подсчет факториала.
Не могу написать код подсчета факториала,а то что вводиться два числа хотелось бы чтобы вводилось 2 числа после выибиралась операцция и если был выбран факториал он считает только 1 число

```
section .data
msg1 db 'please enter the number 1:'
lmsg1 equ  $ - msg1
msg2 db 'please enter the number 2:'
lmsg2 equ  $ - msg2
msg3 db '1.Add '
lmsg3 equ  $ - msg3
msg4 db '2.Substract '
lmsg4 equ  $ - msg4
msg5 db '3.Multiply '
lmsg5 equ  $ - msg5
msg6 db '4.Divide '
lmsg6 equ  $ - msg6
msg7 db 'Operation'
lmsg7 equ  $ - msg7
msg8 db 'Result:'
lmsg8 equ  $ - msg8
msg9 db 'Invalid Option'
lmsg9 equ  $ - msg9
nlinea db 10,10,0
lnlinea equ $ - nlinea

section .bss
opc resb 2
num1 resb 2
num2 resb 2
result resb 2
section .text          
   global _start

_start:      
;ENTER THE NUMBER ~1  
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,msg1
mov edx,lmsg1
int 80h

mov eax,3
mov ebx,0
mov ecx,num1
mov edx,2
int 80h
;ENTER THE NUMBER~2
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,msg2
mov edx,lmsg2
int 80h

mov eax,3
mov ebx,0
mov ecx,num2
mov edx,2
int 80h
;ADD
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,msg3
mov edx,lmsg3
int 80h
;SUBSTRACT
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,msg4
mov edx,lmsg4
int 80h
;MULTIPLY
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,msg5
mov edx,lmsg5
int 80h
; DIVIVDE
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,msg6
mov edx,lmsg6
int 80h
;CHOICE OPERATION
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,msg8
mov edx,lmsg8
int 80h
mov ebx,0
mov ecx,opc
mov edx,2
mov eax,3
int 80h
mov ah,[opc]
sub ah, '0'
cmp ah,1
je add
cmp ah,2
je substract
cmp ah,3
je multiply
cmp ah,4
je divide

mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,msg9
mov edx,lmsg9
int 80h
jmp exit
add:
mov al,[num1]
mov bl,[num2]
sub al,'0'
sub bl,'0'
add al,bl
add al,'0'
mov [result], al
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,msg8
mov edx,lmsg8
int 80h
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,result
mov edx,1
int 80h

jmp exit
substract:
mov al,[num1]
mov bl,[num2]
sub al,'0'
sub bl,'0'
sub al,bl
add al,'0'
mov [result], al
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,msg8
mov edx,lmsg8
int 80h
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,result
mov edx,1
int 80h
jmp exit
multiply:
mov al,[num1]
mov bl,[num2]
sub al,'0'
sub bl,'0'
mul bl
add ax,'0'
mov [result], ax
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,msg8
mov edx,lmsg8
int 80h
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,result
mov edx,1
int 80h
jmp exit
divide:
mov al,[num1]
mov bl,[num2]
mov dx,0
mov ah,0
sub al,'0'
sub bl,'0'
div bl
add ax,'0'
mov [result], ax
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,msg8
mov edx,lmsg8
int 80h
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,result
mov edx,1
int 80h
jmp exit
 exit:
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,nlinea
mov edx,lnlinea
int 80h

mov eax,1
mov ebx,0
int 80h
```

Comment: Для начала вам надо переписать этап ввода данных, потому что у факториала только один параметр. Так что выполняемую операцию стоит вводить первой и в зависимости от нее решать сколько запросить параметров. (Ну или вводить первое число, потом операцию и потом, если это не факториал, второй параметр).

Comment: А вообще не ясно с какими сложностями вы столкнулись в добавлении этой операции. Поясните в вопросе, что именно вызывает затруднения

Comment: А еще у вас же в меню нет ни одного перевода каретки, оно на экране одной строкой будет идти, так и задумано ?. И переводы каретки, как и пробелы  можно выводить прямо внутри текста, так что все меню с операциями можно вывести как одно единое сообщение, а не разбивать его на кучу переменных

Comment: я пояснил проблему лучше в описании

Comment: На счет каретки,да так и задумывалось

Comment: а меню приходилось писать так как могу,потому что только начинаю знакомиться с этим языком программирования

Comment: Сам расчет простой, помещаем в EAX 1, EDX=0, в EBX наше число. Если EBX=0 - то результат =1, это отдельно проверяем. Если он не 0, то выполняем M: MUL EBX //  DEC EBX //  JNZ M. Все, в EDX:EAX результат.

Comment: Как и в любом другом языке программирования, старайтесь выносить одинаковый код в одну точку, а не повторять его множество раз. Например перевод символьного десятичного представления чисел во внутреннее стоит сделать один раз, сразу после ввода. А не дублировать в вычислении для каждой операции. Полезно завести для этого функцию и вызывать ее (так как переводить надо 2 числа)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Расчет факториала:

```
    mov ebx, X   ; заносим уже подготовленное число
                 ; т.е. переведенное из десятичного символьного представления
                 ; в двоичное внутреннее представление
    xor edx, edx ; edx = 0
    mov eax, 1   ; eax = 1
    cmp ebx, 0
    jz  fresult  ; Факториал 0 равен 1 (уже находиться в eax)
 fm:
    mul ebx      ; edx:eax *= ebx
    dec ebx      ; ebx=ebx-1
    jnz fm       ; пока ebx не станет 0 - продолжаем умножать
 fresult:
 ; В регистровой паре edx:eax находиться результат, переводим в десятичное представление
 ; и выдаем пользователю
```

Умножение происходит "задом наперед" 5! = (1) * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1. Так код получается короче, не надо постоянно сверять не достиг ли множитель требуемого числа, выходим из цикла по достижении нуля